Derive properties of indifference curves from preference relation
For context I'm a pure maths undergrad and I'm trying to self-study basic microeconomics concepts. I know about metric spaces but not a lot about point set topology.
What I'm trying to do specifically is to use assumed properties of a preference relation to derive properties of indifference curves, like them existing in the first place, being convex and non-intersecting, etc, but I can't figure out how to bridge the gap.
If I've understood correctly, it's common to imagine the set of all possible bundles as the set $\mathbb{R}_+^n$. We then imagine an agents preferences as a binary relation $\precsim$ on $\mathbb{R}_+^n$ that is

Total
Reflexive
Transitive
Monotonic
Order dense
Continuous
Convex

From $\precsim$ we get $\prec$ and $\sim$ with expected properties.
From this I think that I should be able to derive the shape of indifference curves.
I'm able to define a specific indifference curve as the set
\begin{gather*}
C_a = \{g \in \mathbb{R}_+^n \:\:|\:\: g \sim a\}
\end{gather*}
for some $a \in \mathbb{R}_+^n$. But after this point I'm at a loss, I imagine for instance that $C_a$ has an uncountable number of elements, but even this I can't manage to prove. A trembling attempt I've made:

I assume there's a mix of two bundles $g, h \in \mathbb{R}_+^n$ such that $g + h \sim a$ (even this assumption I can't justify but let's leave that for now). As a result of the relation being strictly monotone I have
\begin{gather*}
g + (1 - \varepsilon)h \prec a
\end{gather*}
for $\varepsilon \in (0, 1)$. Now I want to claim that there is some $\delta > 0$ such that
\begin{gather*}
(1 + \delta)g + (1 - \varepsilon)h \sim a
\end{gather*}
and thus $(1 + \delta)g + (1 - \varepsilon)h$ is also a point on the indifference curves.
The problem is that I don't know how to justify my claim of the existence of such an $\delta$. Maybe I can first observe that $a \prec (1 + \delta)g + h$ and then use continuity or strict convexity to show that $(1 + \delta)g + (1 - \varepsilon)h \sim a$, but that's a vague sketch and I haven't been able to make it any more concrete than that.

Are there any small hints that can help me on the way? Or am I heading in the wrong direction / not understood the basics correctly? Also if anyone happens to have recommendations for reading materials geared towards someone with some math knowledge but no prior microeconomics exposure I'd greatly appreciate. This far I've mainly pieced different Wikipedia articles and online lecture notes together.

I'm not sure which property of indifference curves/sets you attempted proof is aimed at, but you may want to check out Kreps (2013), in particular chapter 2.4.
